# Echo message based on payment method (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’d like to show a message on the thankyou page, based on the customer’s payment method.

So if the customer paid with paypal, the message “Thanks for ordering with paypal” will appear on the order received page.

Answer (score 0):

WC versions > 2.6 already does this by default. Look at the `thankyou.php` WC template file and you'll see L56 uses `<?php echo $order->payment_method_title; ?>` to echo the payment method.