# Display a custom text based on payment methods in Woocommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

In Woocommerce I'm trying to display a message based on the payment method that the customer selects when an order is submitted. I have 2 payment methods, **BACS** and **Cheque** and I need to display a different message for each one.

[I just found that you can put a message on the page of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289105/echo-message-based-on-payment-method-woocommerce) thankyou.php

but I would need this custom message to appear on the order page and also to be added to the pdf invoice *(I am using WooCommerce PDF Invoices plugin)*.

Answer (score 3):

The following will first save a custom message based on payment gateways as custom order meta data (custom-fields)… This will allow you to set this order custom field in your PDF invoice with much more ease *(see the note at the end)*:

```
// Save payment message as order item meta data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_custom_message_based_on_payment', 10, 2 );
function save_custom_message_based_on_payment( $order, $data ){
    if ( $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method() ) {
        if ( $payment_method === 'cheque' ) {
            // For Cheque
            $message = __("My custom message for Cheque payment", "woocommerce");
        } elseif ( $payment_method === 'bacs' ) {
            // Bank wire
            $message = __("My custom message for Bank wire payment", "woocommerce");
        }
        // save message as custom order meta data (custom field value)
        if ( isset($message) )
            $order->update_meta_data( '_payment_message', $message );
    }
}
```

Then the following will display this custom message on Order received page, view order page and email notifications, using hooks *(not changing templates)*:

```
// On "Order received" page (add payment message)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'thankyou_custom_payment_message', 10, 2 );
function thankyou_custom_payment_message( $text, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) return; 
    if ( $message = $order->get_meta( '_payment_message' ) ) {
        $text .= '<br><div class="payment-message"><p>' . $message . '</p></div>' ;
    }
    return $text;
}

// On "Order view" page (add payment message)
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'view_order_custom_payment_message', 5, 1 );
function view_order_custom_payment_message( $order_id ){
    if ( $message = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_payment_message', true ) ) {
        echo '<div class="payment-message"><p>' . $message . '</p></div>' ;
    }
}

// Email notifications display (optional)
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_order_instruction_email', 10, 4 );
function add_order_instruction_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if( $sent_to_admin )
        return;
    elseif( $text = $order->get_meta('_payment_message') )
        echo '<div style="border:2px solid #e4e4e4;padding:5px;margin-bottom:12px;"><strong>Note:</span></strong> '.$text.'</div>';
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

---

**Note for PDF Invoice**

> **The rule on stackOverFlow is one question at the time**, so for one question one answer, to avoid your question be closed as too broad.

As there is many different PDF invoices plugins for Woocommerce, you will have [to read the developer documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/pdf-invoice-developer-tools/) for the WooCommerce PDF Invoices plugin, to display that custom message in the PDF invoices.

Comment: Thank you @loictheaztec , for the answer and for edit a question. i used a google transletBut it does not work. 
about your code, where i will see on order view page , the payment message? I dont see in a meta data item. neither in a billing data

Comment: i found it in a order page , in my account. on the front end.  i would like appear in the edit order in the back end.

Comment: Dear, LoicTheAztec. When the customer is logged out of his user account, but still enters the address of his successful order in the browser on the line  
  `if ( $message = $order->get_meta( '_payment_message' ) ) {`   
I get an error, how do I handle this error?

Comment: This doesn't throw any error… The error is somewhere else in your case.

Comment: Yes, it does not display any error unless, for example, the customer has logged out of his account and enters the link of a successful order, for example
`https://test.com/checkout/order-received/9236262/?key=wc_order_ol2BCw72G6626&wc_status=success`

Comment: I added just before `if ( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) return;`… It should solve the problem.